# Django админ отобразить в форме картинку

Tags: python, django

Получилось показывать картинки в списке

model.py

```
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='xxx/', null=True, blank=True)

    def image_tag(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.image.url)
        else:
            return 'No Image Found'

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

[image: список]

но ни как не получается сделать тоже самое для формы добавления

admin.py

```
class NewsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    body = forms.CharField(label='Текст', widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
    image = ['image_tag']

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(News)
class NewsAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'body_text_preview', 'image_tag']
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    form = NewsAdminForm
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь в админку `readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)`

Comment: Это работает, но только при редактировании. Когда новую добавляешь ничего не отображается.

Comment: Ну тогда ищи html страницу админки и вместо <a href=> пиши <img src=>